# Find a directory containing desired text and stored all that files into another folder

Tags: python, filesystems

How can we identify files of desired text in a file of the same directory and then separate all those files into another directory?

```
import os
user_input = input('What is the name of your directory')
directory = os.listdir(user_input)
searching = input('What word are you trying to find?')
for fname in directory:
    if os.path.isfile(user_input + os.sep + fname):
        # Full path
        f = open(user_input + os.sep + fname, 'r')

        if searching in f.read():
            print('found string in file %s' % fname)
        else:
            print('string not found')
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

[shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) has many methods you can use. One of which is:

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

# 2nd option
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

You can copy those file into another location.

by adding

```
if searching in f.read():
            print('found string in file %s' % fname)
            shutil.copy(user_input + os.sep + fname,destination)
```